# Scrape information using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape information as shown below but they will provide the wrong output. what mistakes am I doing? this is page link https://www.thegrommet.com/products/the-vintage-pearlmini-peas-in-the-pod-necklace

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'book'
    start_urls = ['https://www.thegrommet.com/gifts/by-type/personalized-gifts']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
    }



    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//div[@class='flex-grow | p-t-s']//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        title=response.xpath("//div[@class='f-heading-xl']//text()").get()
        title=title.strip()
        d3=response.xpath("//div[@class='accordion-section | p-t-s p-b-m']")
        for pro in d3:
            data=[tup for tup in pro.xpath('//div//text()')]
            try:
                trip=data[1].get()
            except:
                trip=''
            trip=trip.strip()
            try:
                tuck=data[2].get()
            except:
                tuck=''
            tuck=tuck.strip()
            try:
                tup=data[3].get()
            except:
                tup=''
            tup=tup.strip()
            
        yield{ 
            'title':title,
            'd1':trip,
            'd2':tuck,
            'd3':tup,
            
            
            }
```

[image]

`PIC2:`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select the xpath expression for `d1,d2,d3` the following way and no need to use try except because scrapy handles None value itself. You  also can use scrapy built-in method which is `normalize-space` to remove leading and trailing Whitespace and Newlines.

**Full working code:**

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'book'
    start_urls = ['https://www.thegrommet.com/gifts/by-type/personalized-gifts']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.62 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//div[@class='flex-grow | p-t-s']//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        title=response.xpath("//div[@class='f-heading-xl']//text()").get()
        title=title.strip()
        
        yield{ 
            'title':title,
            'd1':response.xpath('normalize-space((//*[@class="accordion-section | p-t-s p-b-m"]/div)[1]/text()[1])').get(),
            'd2':response.xpath('normalize-space((//*[@class="accordion-section | p-t-s p-b-m"]/div)[2]/text()[1])').get(),
            'd3':response.xpath('normalize-space((//*[@class="accordion-section | p-t-s p-b-m"]/div)[3]/text()[1])').get(),
            'url':response.url
            
            }
```